# Why Bitset allows values distinct from 1 and 0?

Tags: java, bitset

I try to learn `BitSet` collection in java. I have read that it uses bits inside.

> Each  * component of the bit set has a {@code boolean} value

I wrote a small application:

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
bitSet.set(9);
bitSet.set(5);
bitSet.set(3);
System.out.println(bitSet);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bitSet.toByteArray()));
```

I was wondered that I can put value different from 1 and 0.

Also I don't understand the output:

```
{3, 5, 9}
[40, 2]
```

Please explain me the usage of this collection?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html No offense - but I would expect a 6k+ user to know how to lookup oracle docs for a collection class, read and understand it...

Comment: @Fildor my quote from this page as you can see

Comment: That's not making it better. Why didn't you understand the docs? How can we give you more or better explanation than that you can read there? To me it is pretty clear. I just want to understand why it isn't for you.

Comment: @Fildor I read doc but don't understand it. I believe that SO suitable for this case

Comment: Fair enough, but it would be helpful to know what you are struggling with exactly. Otherwise people will end up more or less repeating the docs - which you did not understand.

Comment: "I was wondered that I can put value different from 1 and 0." `bitSet.set(3);` does not "set" the value 3. It sets the value **at position** 3 to 1. So you are still setting 0 and 1 but you say which one. Imagine if there were a Bit class, it would be like having a Bit[] and setting a value at some specific index like `Bit[] mybits = new Bit[n]; mybits[3] = 1;`

Comment: @Fildor, thanks I understood

Comment: @Fildor, why it calls BitSet rather than BitList ?

Comment: "why it calls bitset rether than bitList" - Probably would be confusing because people would expect it to implement the List interface. On the other hand it does not implement Set ... honestly: I don't know. But it's just a name.

Comment: @Fildor I believe that naming is main reason of my misunderstanding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BitSet` logically represents a "vector of bits that grows as needed" ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)).

When you create it via `new BitSet()`, you have all bits set to 0 (false).

```
0    5    10
|    |    |
000000000000... (virtually infinite sequence)
```

Using `set(x)` you set to 1 (true) the bit at position *x* (where the first position is 0); e.g. in your code you enable bits 3, 5 and 9.

```
0    5    10
|    |    |
000101000100...
```

`toString()` reports the list of bits set to 1, i.e. 3, 5 and 9 in the example.

`toByteArray()` converts the contents of the `BitSet` to a sequence of `byte` values, each containing the value of 8 contiguous bits, in little-endian order (i.e. starting from least indices in the `BitSet`). The output `{40, 2}` in your example comes from:

```
 7      0   15     8    <- position in BitSet
 |      |   |      |
{00101000 , 00000010}   <- toByteArray(), binary
    |          |
{  40     ,    2    }   <- toByteArray(), decimal
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additional question: when I declare `BitSet bits = new BitSet(8);` then I can without issues execute `bits.set(15);` or retrieve `bits.get(85);` (exaggerating, I know, but just to show the point).  When looking to the implementation of `public void set(int bitIndex)` in `BitSet.java` then I see only an exception thrown when the index is negative (fair enough).  But why not when you exceed the max. number of bits set in the constructor?   I've also seen that the constructor `public BitSet(int nbits)` doesn't hold a local variable to keep track of the number of bits passed in the constructor...

Comment: @GeertVc The N you pass to `new BitSet(N)` is like an _estimated_ size of the bitset and is used to allocate the internal bits storage. If you set a bit over such size, the `BitSet` has to expand the internal storage to allocate it, but it still allows to do it.This same principle is used in other `java.util` collection classes, e.g. `new ArrayList(10)` creates a list initially backed by an array of size 10, but still allows to add more than 10 elements allocating a larger array if necessary.

Answer (score 8):

You set the bits number 3, 5 and 9:

```
byte#      1                 0
index  … 9 8   7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
value  … 1 0   0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Binary `10` is decimal `2` (2¹ = 2).

Binary `00101000` is decimal `40` (2³ + 2⁵ = 8 + 32 = 40).

Comment: @gstackoverflow a byte is 8 bits wide. So 2^9 ends up in a second byte, so that's going to be 00000010 => 2 in the byte with index 1.

Comment: @gstackoverflow, please add a comment instead of directly modifying user answers, especially when you haven't understood the content yet: you removed the meaningful space between 8 and 7 : http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41847776/revisions

Answer (score 4):

[BitSet.set(int bitIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set(int)) sets the bit at the specified index to true.

So `bitSet.set(9);` flips bit number 9 to 1

On output:

- `System.out.println(bitSet);` prints the result of [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#toString())  which is according to JavaDoc:

> for every index for which this BitSet contains a bit in the set state, the decimal representation of that index is included in the result. S

- `Arrays.toString(bitSet.toByteArray())` prints [byte representation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#toByteArray()) of BitSet.

Step by step, it splits your binary set: 1000101000

to bytes: 10 00101000

which is 2 and 40 in decimal.